# Web scraping with R - How to click on a button in a dynamic web page using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, r, ajax, web-scraping

How can I modify the following **R** code to extract the Quarterly data? I'm trying get data from Yahoo Finance which is a dynamic web-page using AJAX thus the address remains the same for both Annual and Quarterly data. The selector is 'button.P\(0px\)'. So far I've managed to extract the Annual data for the Income Statement table for AAPL but still struggling to get Quarterly data. Any suggestion is welcomed :)

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL'
webpage <- read_html(url)
tableIS <- html_table(html_nodes(webpage,'table.Lh\\(1\\.7\\)'), header = NA, trim = TRUE, fill = FALSE, dec = ".")
print (tableIS)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going in the right direction.

```
result <- read.csv("http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?&t=XNAS:AAPL&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&reportType=is&period=3&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=5&curYearPart=1st5year&rounding=3&view=raw&r=865827&denominatorView=raw&number=3", skip=1)
print(result)
```

You may be interested in this as well.

```
# financial metrics and ratios
read.csv("http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?&t=AAPL",header=T,stringsAsFactors = F,skip = 2)[,-c(12)]->spreadsheet
View(spreadsheet)
```

Comment: Thanks bro, much appreciated your help. It works nicely!

Just thinking loudly, do you think it would be possible to implement a similar code for scrapping Yahoo Finance webpage?

I have been following the js container while clicking on Annual/Quarterly button, this is the msg:
//cdn.mookie1.com/containr.js?at=1&anId=6862&advId=434861&campId=26326417&pubId=273&chanId=134644197&placementId=300x250&adsafe_par=&bidurl=https%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fquote%2FAAPL%2Ffinancials&bidPr=&uId=&impId=3899873530262390300&BEGIN__ADSAFE=&prc=1047638&END__ADSAFE=

Comment: I looked into that very same thing a long time ago.  I never figured out why both Annual and Quarterly use the same exact URL.  I think you need to use Selenium to click the 'Quarterly' link and then scrape the data when the page refreshes.  I don't know exactly how to do that with R.  I can do it with Python, but that doesn't help much here.